# Read .gz file written by gzwirte (zlib) uncorrectly in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, zlib

The .gz file was written by a C program that called gzputs & gzwrite.

I list the compressed file contents by `gzip -l`, and find the `uncompressed` value is uncorrectly. This value seems to be equal to the bytes that the latest `gzputs` or `gzwrite` writed into the .gz file. That makes the `ratio` a nagitive value.

An error occurred when these .gz files used as input of Map/Reduce. Only part of the .gz file  can be read in map phase seems. (Size of the part seems to be equal to the above `uncompressed` value).

Someone can teach me what should I do in the C program or Map/Reduce ?

Comment: If you gunzip the file, what you get back, as compared to what you thought you wrote?  Did you gzclose() the file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I `gunzip` and `gzip` again, the file will be OK. I guess the reason may be that `gzputs` will write several new lines to a compressed file each time, but `gzip` compress the whole file directly. Read error in Map/Reduce seems to a [bug of GZIPInputStream](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4691425). I have found a GZIPInputStream-like class that can read gz file correctly from Internet. Then I extended and customized the TextInputFormat and LineRecordReader in hadoop. The problem has been solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Read error in Map/Reduce seems to be [a bug of GZIPInputStream](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4691425).

I have found a GZIPInputStream-like class from Internet that can read gz file correctly. Then I extended and customized the TextInputFormat and LineRecordReader in hadoop. It works now.

Comment: Why not simply updating to the latest java 1.6/1.7?

Comment: Hadoop cluster is supported by others and we just submit MapReduce job.

Comment: Why not simply ask them to update to the latest java 1.6/1.7?

Comment: Much applications are running on the cluster. Update jdk only for us is not accepted.